# Нужно чтобы в результате работы программы XML файл доступный по ссылке

Tags: python, xml

Здравстсвуйте,взял заказ на парсер.В тз написано что с сайта должны парситься товары в формате XML и файл должен быть доступным по ссылке. С первым проблем нету но как загрузить я не знаю, сервисов дающих такой фунционал я не знаю.Желательно чтобы ссылка не менялась.Зарвние спасибо за советы.
P.S. Пишу на Python

Comment: Те вы взяли заказ, который не знаете, как делать. И предлагаете сделать нам?

Comment: нет,мне просто не кажется это большой проблемой,и меня есть в голове варианты как это можно сделать,но они колхозные и медленные. Надеялся на совет от людей которые разбираются лучше меня в вопросе.

Comment: Так покажите ваш колхозный и медленный вариант.

Comment: Тебе верно сказали, пока это выглядит так, будто ты хочешь, что бы за тебя выполнили заказ. Покажи свой код, каким бы он не был, тогда подскажут

Comment: Чего вы напали на человека? Нормальный вопрос (может формально и не очень подходящий по оформлению, правилами и т.д.), но точно вообще не вижу в нем ничего про "сделайте за меня". Я вижу вопрос про то, как организовать хранение файлов с доступом из интернета. Очевидно, что эта одна функция, которую человек не знает, как реализовать, т.к. не сталкивался, и не просит этого делать за него, а спрашивает про подход.

Comment: Cпасибо за поддержку,но как я сделал сам скину,ток позже немного. Первый раз просто спрашиваю что-то,не знал что тут так устроено,впредь буду знать)